# Cannot launch VS Code from WSL terminal after disabled the path sharing feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have export path in .bashrc. But when type`code` in terminal, there is no response.

Debug output:

```
+ COMMIT=e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
+ APP_NAME=code
+ QUALITY=stable
+ NAME=Code
+ DATAFOLDER=.vscode
+ realpath /mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin
+ VSCODE_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code
+ ELECTRON=/mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe
+ IN_WSL=false
+ [ -n Ubuntu-20.04 ]
+ IN_WSL=true
+ [ true = true ]
+ export WSLENV=ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE/w:WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID
+ wslpath -m /mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js
+ CLI=C:/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js
+ WSL_EXT_ID=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
+ ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 /mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe C:/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js --locate-extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
+ cat /tmp/remote-wsl-loc.txt
+ WSL_EXT_WLOC=
+ [ -n  ]
+ ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 /mnt/c/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe C:/Users/Chen/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js .
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this will help you to get useful answers to your question

Comment: Seems be the same issue as I have: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3831